# Calculating VAR(Y) given VAR(X) and RMSE

Tags: regression, variance

I feel like this is a calculation I've done before but can't recall how, and Google searches don't seem to answer my question.  Before I describe the calculation I want to do, let me first set up the scenario:

I have a process which produces a coating thickness.  Currently the thickness variation is unacceptable.  Let's say thickness Y is a function of one known variable ($X$) by $$y=a+bX+error$$ and I currently have $VAR(Y)$, $VAR(X)$, and $VAR(error)$ from the $RMSE$ of the regression equation.  The proposal is to improve the method of control of $X$ to reduce $X$ variation but it won't be perfect.  Here is what (I think) I understand:

- If $RMSE=0$, then $VAR(Y)=b^2*VAR(X)$ since $VAR(Y)$ would only depend on $VAR(X)$
- If $X$ were perfectly fixed with perfect control and no variation, then $VAR(Y) = RMSE^2$

So my question is, can I predict the new $VAR(Y)$ assuming the $VAR(errors)$ is constant but given a new, reduced $VAR(X)$?  I need to understand this in order to justify the expense of the better controller.  From the simulated data, it seems that $VAR(Y)$ is roughly $b^2*VAR(X_{new})+RMSE^2$ but the numbers don't match exactly and I'm afraid I might be completely wrong.